# Trying to track rotation of semicircles on the map with the heading in iOS of iPhone game

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Drawing semicircles (half circles) on the map and they worked great until I turned on tracking.  Now the semicircle radius increases as the heading changes.  I need the four semicircles, which are oriented North, South, East or West, to rotate with the map view and compass and stay oriented N,S,E or W and scale with zoom. Below is a sample of the existing code. It worked fine until tracking was turned on. The semicircles are being drawn and I have the heading there. Initially I thought I just needed to add the heading to the start and end points but then I realized the original code doesn't work with the tracking.

```
    MapViewController.m

    if([[dict2 valueForKey:@"missile_type"] isEqualToString:@"East"]) {  circle.r1 = -M_PI/2; circle.r2 = M_PI/2;  }
    if([[dict2 valueForKey:@"missile_type"] isEqualToString:@"West"]) {  circle.r1 = M_PI/2; circle.r2 = -M_PI/2; }
    if([[dict2 valueForKey:@"missile_type"] isEqualToString:@"North"]) { circle.r1 = M_PI; circle.r2 = 0;  }
    if([[dict2 valueForKey:@"missile_type"] isEqualToString:@"South"]) {   circle.r1 = 0; circle.r2 = M_PI;
     //     circle.r1 = degreesToRadians(0 + titleBarObject.heading); circle.r2 = degreesToRadians(180 + titleBarObject.heading);  
    }

    double interval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    circle.impactInterval = interval + [[dict2 objectForKey:@"countdown"] intValue];

    [circleObjects setObject:circle forKey:newAttackID];



    ASCircleAnnotationView.m

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = myAnnotation.coordinate;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D ciclePointCoord = myAnnotation.coordinate;

    ciclePointCoord.latitude +=         (360/40000000.f)*myAnnotation.radius/**cos((ciclePointCoord.longitude/180)*M_PI)*/;

    CGPoint point = [self.mainView.mapView convertCoordinate:centerCoord         toPointToView:self];
    CGPoint point2= [self.mainView.mapView convertCoordinate:ciclePointCoord toPointToView:self];

    float radius =  point2.y - point.y;

    if (radius< 0) {
        radius = -radius;
    }

    if(myAnnotation.r1==0 && myAnnotation.r2==0)
        myAnnotation.r2 = 2*M_PI;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, myAnnotation.r1, myAnnotation.r2, 0);

    // Added as failed experiment to rotate annotation. 
    // MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self.mainView.mapView viewForAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    // annotationView.transform =         CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((titleBarObject.heading/57.2958));

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Comment: What **language** have you written your code in? Please remember to add the relevant tags to your question.

Comment: Objective C.  Thanks!